# Trying to populate two comboboxes based upon selection of another combobox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I've been searching this issue on Microsoft, Stackoverflow, techinthenet.com and several others, with no real solution that I can find.

I am trying to get two comboboxes (cboCourse and cboVols) to populate based on the selection of cboTrainee_Name.  The code for the first combobox is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [qryBooks].[PName] FROM qryBooks WHERE qryBooks.Complete=No ORDER BY [qryBooks].[PName];
```

Everywhere I've searched gives assistance and samples to populate the first combobox, then the second combobox based upon what is selected in the first.  I need both cboCourse and cboVols to populate based on the result of the same query.  What I have so far is:

```
Private Sub cboTrainee_Name_AfterUpdate()

    cboCourse.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT [qryBooks].[Book] FROM qryBooks WHERE [qryBooks].[PName]=[Forms]![frmIntro]![cboTrainee_Name] ORDER BY [qryBooks].[Book];"

    cboVol.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT [qryBooks].[Vols] FROM qryBooks WHERE [qryBooks].[PName]=[Forms]![frmIntro]![cboTrainee_Name] ORDER BY [qryBooks].[Vols];"

End Sub
```

This works for cboCourse, but cboVols will not populate.  I know there has to be a simple explanation.  Any suggestions?

ADDED!  I used SELECT DISTINCT because each column in the query contains multiple instances of the same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problems with your SQL.

You might need to call the Requery method on both combo boxes to get them to refresh after cboTrainee_Name is changed:

```
cboCourse.Requery
cboVol.Requery
```

Note that you don't have to set the RowSource property in code for this to work. You should be able to plug in your SQL statements as is in the RowSource property and just the Requery method on the dependent combo boxes in the AfterUpdate event of your cboTrainee_Name combo box.

Comment: I placed the SELECT statements under the RowSource of each cbo, and plugged the requery statements under the cboTrainee_Name AfterUpdate event.  It still does the same thing; populates and refreshs cboCourse as needed, but no data in cboVol.

Comment: Is it possible that you don't have in the qryBooks query for the selected Trainee_Name?

Comment: Also, double-check your Bound Column, Column Count, and Column Widths settings on cboVol versus those on cboCourse. It's possible for there to be underlying data that isn't visible due to a formatting configuration. You can compare the two combo boxes, but as a short cut, just delete cboVol, copy-paste cboCourse and change the control name and RowSource property.

Comment: I tried your shortcut.  After playing with the requery statements, I finally got it to do what I needed.  Much Thanks.